# How to run sleep command in Vagrant file

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I've a Vagrant file. Once in a file while running vagrant, rsync failing and resulting instance become useless(sometimes sshd process restarting after destination AWS instance once available). I would like sleep the vagrant rsync process for ~20 sec and start the rsync to the destination instance. So, not to worry about the sshd process. I tried below commands in the Vagrant file but no luck(specified below commands before the rsync run). can someone help me please

Trial 1:

```
 puts "Sleep for a while to keep SSH alive"
 sleep(20)
```

Trial 2:

```
   config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Sleep for a while to keep SSH alive;sleep 20"
```

**Vagrantfile:**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 FOLDERS_TO_SYNC = {
      "." => "/folder1",
      "../folder2" => "/folder2"
  }

config.vm.provider "aws" do |aws, override|
.....
  override.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Sleep for a while to keep SSH alive; sleep 20"
  override.vm.synced_folder "folder1", "dest/folder1", type: "rsync", create: true
  override.vm.synced_folder "folder2", "dest/folder2", type: "rsync", create: true

  end

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
...
end
```

end

Vagrant v1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that, in my case 10 seconds was necessary.

This is a line in my Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "cp #{host_sync_folder}/Resources/settings.xml /.m2 2>/dev/null || :; sleep 10"
```

I see in your trial 2, that you are missing an empty space between ; and sleep command.

Please try it out and let me know.

Comment: config.vm.provision is not working for me. we are using chef provisioning. where as in for the provider is **AWS**
(overriding the folders). I'm trying to include sleep command before the **override.vm.synced_folder**.  Tried this one `override.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Sleep for a while to keep SSH alive; sleep 20"`  (but not getting the expected outcome) -  I've updated my post with some Vagrant file content. Please check

Comment: No. it didn't give any errors. config.vm.provision is not working as expected, however override.vm.provision is overriding chef provision. we are running vagrant command as `vagrant up --provider=aws || vagrant provision` 
(we've couple of different providers in vagrant file)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows/PowerShell

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "Start-Sleep -s 15"
```

worked for me, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep#examples).